# Entity framework - right join to a view

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 entities in my db context:

Employee
EmployeeHolidayEntitlement

I *think* it's a fairly normal one-one relationship - but Employee can exist without EmployeeHolidayEntitlement, but EmployeeHolidayEntitlement cannot exist without Employee

Employee is mapped to a **view** in my database
EmployeeHolidayEntitlement is a **table**

My classes are:

**EmployeeHolidayEntitlement**

```
[Table("tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement")]
public class EmployeeHolidayEntitlement
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public decimal StandardEntitlement { get; set; }

    //.....omitted for brevity
}
```

**Employee**

```
[Table("vEmployee")] //note v - it's a view
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When building my context, I do:
(not sure if this is correct!)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeHolidayEntitlement>()
  .HasRequired(w => w.Employee)
  .WithOptional();
```

When querying, if possible, I would like one EmployeeEntitlement record for each Employee (weather it exists in tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement or not) -

My query currently looks like this:

```
from
    userEntitlement in db.ADUserHolidayEntitlement
 join
    adUser in db.ADUsers
    on
    userEntitlment.EmployeeNumber equals adUser.EmployeeNumber
select userEntitlement
```

But this is (i think) doing a LEFT join -
It's only returning the 2 entities that have an entry in tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement

I would imagine the resultant SQL needs to look something like:

```
SELECT 
employee.EmployeeNumber, 
employeeHol.* 

FROM tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement employeeHol

RIGHT JOIN vEmployee employee
ON 
employeeHol.EmployeeNumber = employee.EmployeeNumber
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is doing an inner join. I believe you're asking to retrieve all employees, and an `EmployeeHolidayEntitlement` for each employee (if it exists).

To perform a left join, use a query similar to this:

```
from adUser in db.ADUsers
join userEntitlement in db.ADUserHolidayEntitlement on
    adUser.EmployeeNumber equals userEntitlment.EmployeeNumber into g
from userEntitlement in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
    adUser, 
    userEntitlement // Will be null of no entitlement exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its doing an inner join just like you asked it to.

You do not need an explicit join at all.

You need something like:

```
from user in db.....
select new{user,user.Entitlement};
```