# Get all rows where a match is found

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm creating a simple blogging system with the following database tables:

```
Posts
    PostId
    Title
    PostDate
    Body
    Draft

Categories
    CategoryId
    CategoryName

PostCategories
    PostId
    CategoryId

Authors
    AuthorId
    AuthorName

PostAuthors
    AuthorId
    PostId

Tags
    TagId
    TagName

PostTags
    PostId
    TagId
```

Here's the query I have so far (using LINQ):

```
 var results = from p in posts 
               join pc in postcategories on p.PostId equals pc.PostId 
               join c in categories on pc.PostId equals c.CategoryId 
               join a in authors on pc.PostId equals a.AuthorId 
               select new BlogViewModel { 
                                          Post = p, 
                                          Category = c, 
                                          Author = a 
                                        };
```

This successfully returns all posts, the category the post belongs to, and the post author. My issue is how to get all associated tags for each post. I used Entity Framework to generate models and `BlogViewModel` contains:

```
public Post Post { get; set; }
public Category Category { get; set; }
public Author Author { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

My gut tells me that I need a new query within the `select new BlogViewModel` statement, something like:

```
... Tags = //new LINQ statement?
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do join with `tags` and `posttags` and then group data on `PostId`:

```
var results = from p in posts
              join pc in postcategories on p.PostId equals pc.PostId
              join c in categories on pc.PostId equals c.CategoryId
              join ap in authorposts on pc.PostId equals ap.PostId
              join a in authors on ap.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId
              join tp in tagposts on p.PostId equals tp.PostId
              join t in tags on tp.TagId equals t.TagId
              group new { t, p, c, a } by tp.PostId into g

              select new BlogViewModel
                        {
                          Post = g.First().p,
                          Category = g.First().c,
                          Author = g.First().a,
                          Tags = g.Select(x=>x.t)
                        };
```

See [working fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yJkMOc)

Comment: So I just got around in to implementing this and it's only returning one post, even though there are two posts in the table (and all of the necessary lines PostCategories, PostAuthors, etc). I had gotten an error relating to using `First()` so I switched it to `FirstOrDefault()`. Could this be my problem? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you in your question, how you did?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you are asking

Comment: I mean where are you having error, can you update your question with how you tried

Comment: @Matt Altepeter I have modified the query, there was a silly mistake, try with updated query

Answer (score -2):

Though I'm not expert in LinQ, but what you need is Left / Right join. You can achieve the same in LinQ using DefaultIfEmpty().

Please take a look at [Entity framework - right join to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388336/entity-framework-right-join-to-a-view) and http://forums.asp.net/t/1728935.aspx?left+right+join+in+linq+or+lambda

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware. Thanks for informing the same.